# What is the best way to programmatically test successful outbound connection to port 443 of a particular website?

Tags: ssl, openssl

I would like to write a program that tests whether a Linux machine is able to make an outbound connection to port 443.

I considered netcat but I believe that doesn't support SSL...

`openssl s_client -connect www.google.com:443` seems to be a simple approach. However, what can I grep from the output of that to determine if connection is successful? Would either of these suffice?

CONNECTED(00000003)

SSL handshake has read 5750 bytes and written 437 bytes
Verification: OK

Comment: "I considered netcat but I believe that doesn't support SSL... " Depends how you define "make an outbound connection". If it is just testing that something remote listen on port 443, without exchanging a single bit of transport data (including TLS records), then `nc` is totally fit for the job (ex: `nc -z -w7 somehost someport`). If you need to test for TLS, you need indeed to start an handshake, like with `openssl s_client` or any program using an "SSL" library to do secure communications.

Comment: "what can I grep from the output of that to determine if connection is successful?" Do you control the remote end? If so, you should put in there something that replies with a specific (arbitrary) things at once when the TLS handshake is finished, and your client application will just need to catch for this canary being seen or not. If you do not control the remote end, but uses a website you should emulate an HTTP(s) communication and at least make sure you get back a successful HTTP reply (so any code starting with 2 or 3)

Comment: "what can I grep from the output of that to determine if connection is successful?" besides the above, commands like `openssl s_client` are not really designed to be parsed, they are really for human consumption.  Read the NOTES part of its manual specifically the beginning (telling you to do HTTP like I wrote above) or the end of it (explaining that it will accept any certificate, which is by itself not necessarily good). Normally in cases like that you should instead rely on the exit code of the command, but you have to double check how openssl behaves there.

Comment: And to remain on topic here and hence speak about programming, you should indeed then write your own program to do the "TLS" check instead of relying on an external command. But then you need to provide more details, starting with the language, and the specific problems you have in writing such program as you can find many examples already of simple TLS client (you should look at monitoring software like Nagios or Icinga or others, as they have plugins to check TLS/HTTPS resources)

Comment: I appreciate the thorough response. I am not too familiar about the specifics of how TLS/SSL work, but I think it's clear it may not be as simple as I thought. I think for my purposes, I would need to start the handshake and determine if communication is successful. The purpose is to ensure a device can transfer data to the https server. I will look at the examples you suggested as well as other resources. Thanks!

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/1629020/whats-a-quick-way-to-check-if-a-tls-handshake-is-possible-with-twitter-com